# Has anyone filmed a total lunar eclipse from the Moon's perspective?

Tags: the-moon, lunar-eclipse

With all of the footage we have of total lunar eclipses, has NASA, ESA, or any other space program ever taken a photo or video of it from the Moon itself?

Comment: Somewhat related: The crew of Apollo 12 witnessed a solar eclipse (Earth eclipsing the Sun) on their way back from the moon. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_12#Return

Comment: With the camera pointed in which direction, towards the sun or earth? If the latter, Joe Blow's answer is great. If the former, there would be nothing to see but the sun.

Comment: @BillDOe If the camera is towards the Earth it is towards the Sun too. Because the Earth does block the Sun from Moon.

Comment: This has also been discussed in Space SE: [this answer to *What would a lunar eclipse look like from the surface of the moon?*](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/5566/12102) shows photos "taken by the SELENE (Kaguya) probe in Feb 2009 during a penumbral eclipse" taken from an altitude of only 50 km above the Moon and links to a lot more. See [this answer to *Has the Earth's red atmosphere rim ever been photographed?*](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/30088/12102) to see images by Surveyor 3 on the Moon and Apollo 11 in transit between the Moon and Earth.

Comment: See also [Have there been any photos taken of a total Earth-Sun eclipse from the Moon, or its vicinity?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/12116/12102) and [Could Apollo astronauts see city lights from the moon?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/38922/12102) Not the same thing, but potentially of interest are [Has the Earth's shadow on the Moon (lunar eclipse) ever been photographed from Space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/29900/12102) and [Star visibility from space](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/55399/12102)

Comment: and [How big of a problem is the Lunar eclipse in April 2014 for LADEE?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/1734/12102)

Answer (score 5):

What can you say but "Wow..."

http://www.space.com/32245-total-solar-eclipse-video-dscovr.html

*"The moon's dark shadow travels across Earth's face in spectacular new views of Tuesday's (March 8) [2016] total solar eclipse captured by a satellite in deep space."*

[image]

I'm sorry my answer is off by about 700,000 miles compared to what you asked :)

I'm fairly sure there did not happen to be, a time when NASA had cameras on the moon, when, there was a lunar eclipse.

Note that cameras today (such as this one on `DSCOVR`) are unbelievably better than cameras from `Apollo` era, so this would blow away any merely 700,000 miles closer imagery captured during the Apollo era.